# Login Interface AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a login interface using tkinter. When the username is admin i'm sending the user to an 'admin interface'. It's returning an attribute error within the tkinter module. I'm slowly learning tkinter and this has me stumped. Below is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
#import modules

from tkinter import *
import os
import pygame
from Mathletics_V2 import *

# Designing window for registration

def register():
    global register_screen
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue", command = register_user).pack()



# Designing window for login 

def login():
    global login_screen
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
    password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command =login_verify).pack()

# Implementing event on register button

def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info, "a+")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info + "\n")
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(register_screen, text="Registration Success", fg="green", font=("calibri", 11)).pack()

# Implementing event on login button 

def login_verify():
    global username1
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        print(username1)
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if username1 == 'admin':
            tMain_Screen()
        elif password1 in verify:
            login_sucess()
        else:
            password_not_recognised()
    else:
        user_not_found()

# Designing popup for login success

def login_sucess():
    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
    Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command=delete_login_success).pack()
    game_intro()

# Designing popup for login invalid password

def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()

# Designing popup for user not found

def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()

# Deleting popups

def delete_login_success():
    login_success_screen.destroy()


def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()


def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()


# Designing Main(first) window

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen #establishs main_screen as a global variable, allows tkinter top level function to utilise window as a root
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    Label(text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command = login).pack()
    Button(text="Registration", height="2", width="30", command= register).pack()
    Button(text="Quit", height="2", width="30", command= quit).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()
#Teacher Screen
def tStudent_Progress():
    global Student_Progress_Screen
    Student_Progress_Screen = Toplevel(Main_Screen)
    Student_Progress_Screen.title("Student Progress")
    Student_Progress_Screen.geometry("500x500")
    Label(Student_Progress_Screen,text="Student Progress").pack()
    #Use while loop to list buttons for registered students

def tgame():
    game_intro()

#def tutorial():
    #Function to Change Tutorial Links

def tMain_Screen():
    global tmain_Screen
    tmain_Screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    tmain_Screen.geometry("300x400")
    tmain_Screen.title("Admin Interface")
    Label("tmain_screen",text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
##    Button(text="Student Progess",height="2", width=" 30", command = tStudent_Progress).pack()
##    Button(text="Game", height="2", width="30", command = tgame).pack()
##    #Button(text="Tutorial",height="2",width="30", command = ttutorial).pack()
##    Label(text="").pack()
##    Button(text="Quit",height="2", width="30",command = quit).pack()

main_account_screen() #Launchs the main account screen via tkinter
```

Here is my error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 100, in login_verify
  File "<string>", line 187, in tMain_Screen
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Tracking the error it's appearing in the line  `Label("tmain_screen",text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()` which is the first label of my admin interface. I've tried utilising different root windows etc.

Comment: It should be `tmain_Screen` not `"tmain_screen"`.there is no `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you used double quotes to call your window name, remove that and it should be fine :)

```
Label(tmain_screen,text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
```

Comment: appreciated, it's always the little things